# How can I install pymavlink to Raspberry?

Tags: python, pip, raspberry-pi2, mavlink

**I wrote this command to install:**

```
sudo pip install pymavlink
```

**and got this error:**

```
ImportError: No module named future

----------------------------------------
Cleaning up...
Command /usr/bin/python -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-gsZblL/pymavlink/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-ppCGHA-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-gsZblL/pymavlink
Storing debug log for failure in /root/.pip/pip.log
```

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem installing this package:

```
$ sudo pip install dronekit
```